# Flutter: change app-brightness according to device ligth/dark mode

Tags: android, flutter, android-dark-theme

#### Setup

*In the main-class of a flutter app:*

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        brightness: Brightness.dark,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Example(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You can set `ThemeData` brightness to dark or light. (I think only from Android OS 10.0, API 29 onward) you can choose in your device settings the screen-tone (light | dark).

#### Example (OP7 pro)

> Settings > Customisation > Tone > Colourful | Light |Dark

When in dark-mode and opening some apps (chrome for example), the app is set to dark. Opening other apps this doesn't happen.

#### Question:

*1) Does your app brightness dynamically update based on device tone-settings if you don't set any `ThemeData` brightness?* (Can't test this myself atm)

*2) If not, how could you dynamically change `ThemeData` brightness based on the device screen tone-setting?*

Comment: i think it's impossible because Tone setting is a proprietary setting and doesn't exist on many devices, but if the user switches between Standart/Dark theme this forces call build() if I'm not mistaken, so you can build you own logic that relied on `MediaQuery.of(context).platformBrightness`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though only suported on IOS 13 and Android 10 (api level 29), and for some browsers (Chrome, firefox, safari, edge).

*More info:*
https://www.howtogeek.com/440920/browsers-are-bringing-automatic-dark-mode-to-websites/

For those wanting to implement this, **Mr. Matt Carroll** has made a blogpost about this:
https://medium.com/flutter/android-dark-theme-in-flutter-9c8070b8b127

#### The Flutter (Dart) - code:

```
MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
    brightness: Brightness.light,
    primaryColor: Colors.red,
  ),
  darkTheme: ThemeData(
    brightness: Brightness.dark,
  ),
);
```

Comment: that's great, anyway to toggle them manually through button in drawer or something like that